# Beta Multiplier - Not Getting Correct Reference Current

Tags: current, cmos, current-mirror

**Solved**: The body of M2 needs to be connected to ground and not to source.

I am reading a textbook on CMOS technology and I am having trouble simulating a beta multiplier in NGSPICE. The reference current, mathematically, states the width of M2 should be 4 times the width of M1 to get a reference current of 20uA. In my spice circuit, I created the same circuit. However, I am getting a current of 30 uA. What is wrong with my circuit?

EDIT: Double-checked by CMOS models and they are exactly the same as the authors and the previous poster.

[image: My Result]
[image: From The Book]

Note: I am using the same model files as the author as it has been tested on every circuit I've done throughout the book.The sizes of the MOSFETs are the same as well as the resistor value.

My Circuit:

```
*** Baker Figure 20.14 Beta Multiplier Reference No Start Up***

.control
destroy all
run
print all
plot I(VME1) (I(VME2))
.endc

.include /home/babadook/Documents/SPICE/models/MOSFET/NMOS_Baker.mod
.include /home/babadook/Documents/SPICE/models/MOSFET/PMOS_Baker.mod

.option scale=1u
.dc VDD1 0 5.0 0.01

VDD1    DD1 0   DC 5
M3  A   B   DD1 DD1 BPMOS L=2 W=30
M4  B   B   DD1 DD1 BPMOS L=2 W=30
M1  A   A   E   E   BNMOS L=2 W=10
M2  B   A   C   C   BNMOS L=2 W=40
VME1    E   0   DC 0
VME2    C   D   DC 0
R   D   0 6.5k
.end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are using the wrong models for your transistors.

Make sure that you have included the level 3 models.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: That does not seem to be it. I just went through every parameter and it is an exact match. What's more: should my circuit be conducting current without the startup circuit?

Comment: Simulators usually try to guess a sensible operating point, therefore no startup circuit is needed. You need one if you put that circuit on silicon. The condition you want to avoid with the startup circuit is that no current is flowing at all.

Comment: I figure it out. The body of M2 is connected to ground in your circuit but mine is connected to source. Why do we need to connect the body to ground??

Comment: NMOS transistors (usually) have a common substrate, which is at the lowest level, ground.